# I try to validate input from a TextField, onKeyEvent

Tags: java, javafx

When press ENTER a method is executed, and if not show a dialog message to user if no value in the field.
Thinking also to do a validation over the input of the user.
I've tried this but every time a key is pressed the message dialog pops up.

```
protected void onTextFieldKeyEnter(KeyEvent event) {
       if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER && !textField.getText().equals("")) {
           onHelloButtonClick();
           textField.clear();
           textField.isFocused();
       } else {
           Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
           alert.setTitle("Atentionare");
           alert.setHeaderText("Informatia nu este corecta!");
           alert.setContentText("Campul nu poate sa fie gol. Introduceti un cif valid");
           alert.showAndWait();
       }
   }
```

Comment: Check if getText().equals(null)  or empty

Comment: [mcve] please.. also make sure to study textfield's api doc: there's an action fired on commit which might be helpful (or not depending on _exact_ requirement :) The other way found: key events might not be a good trigger for validation because they don't cover all possibilities to change the text

Comment: Don't do this.  Use TextFormatter instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` is executed every time an input was made except of ENTER. So you should change to `else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER)` or move your validation like

```
if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
    if (!textField.getText().equals("")) {
        onHelloButtonClick();
        textField.clear();
        textField.isFocused();
    } else {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Atentionare");
        alert.setHeaderText("Informatia nu este corecta!");
        alert.setContentText("Campul nu poate sa fie gol. Introduceti un cif valid");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. I finally understand that my condition is missed placed.. just before your answer I made it work.. Looking at your answer I realise that yours is much cleaner. Cheers mate.. and happy coding